# MongoDB allow access only from specific hosts

Tags: mysql, mongodb, authentication, authorization

In MongoDB 2.4, i want a user can access to **mongod** instance **from only allowed hosts** as MySQL can handle.

In MySQL, as you know when giving rights to a user, you can specify this user from this host etc... like below;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But i couldn't find equivalent of this in MongoDB even i searched a lot at google.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, we can handle this requirement by adding a rule to our firewall, but i'm wondering is it possible with MongoDB directly

Comment: You are better off using a firewall for this, MongoDB isn't really designed to be a firewall

Comment: @Sammaye thanks for your comment. yes i know MongoDB isn't designed to be a firewall, but i'm wondering is MongoDB handling this requirement in it's database layer as MySQL can do?

Comment: Nah, this isn't currently something that is considered MongoDBs job, though auth is under going a overhaul so maybe in the next couple of versions, but there needs to be a compelling reason for MongoDB doing this instead of something specifically designed for it